# running latex on remote host with tramp

Tags: tramp

I'm trying to run latex on remote host from the local host with tramp. 
But it seems that it cannot find the file. To be more specific:

**Update**

1. start emacs on localhost:
2. /ssh:user@remotehost:/tmp/test.tex
3. compile latex on remote host using C-c C-c
4. error cannot find the file test.tex
   " ! I can't find file `test.tex'."

so I guess it's trying to find `/ssh:user@remotehost:/tmp/test.tex` but somehow cannot find it. May be it should look for `/tmp/test.tex`

I've tried `knitr` as well and found that it tries to execute
`/ssh:user@remotehost:foobar.rnw"`.

I think it should use the /ssh command since the program is running locally but I can't grasp what's happening.

Any help?

**Update 2**
Works fine when using emacs -Q. See comment below. will keep you posted once I have found what's wrong in the .emacs.

**Update 3**
The problem does not lies in the .emacs file though. I commented out everything in the .emacs and still got the same issue. I'll continue the investigation. But we are getting there.

**Update 4**
As suggested in the comments below firing emacs with the -Q option works find. I've got good results even with emacs -q.

Launching emacs -q is supposed to prevent loading the .emacs and the default.el files at startup. I place `(setq inhibit-default-init 1)` in my .emacs file and commented the rest of the commands. Therefore only the command `(setq inhibit-default-init 1)` is active in my .emacs file.

I launch emacs without any options and load tramp by hand `(require 'tramp)` and tried latex again but still no success.

I must be missing something that the -q option does not load but I can't figure it out right now.

Comment: What syntax did you try specifically?  I suspect it could not find your file on the remote. It should probably be something like: /ssh:user@remotehost:~foobar.rnw  assuming the file is in your home directory. If your username is the same on the remote, that can be omitted.

Comment: yes you are right. I've modified the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot follow what you have tried to call. Could you pls give the exact key sequence you have applied to Emacs? It is also important which is your current buffer, it must be one having `default-directory` pointing to the remote host.

Comment: I've updated the question hoping that I'm precise enough. Please let me know if i can provide more details

Comment: Calling `C-c` does nothing for me. Do you mean `C-c C-f` (aka `M-x tex-file`)? Do you load latex specific packages, or could you reproduce the problem starting "emacs -Q"?

Comment: apologies I meant `C-c C-c`. By the way I use auctex.  No need to laod any package, it doesn't even find the file to be compiled

Comment: If you do   M-: (setq debug-on-error t)     Then try to compile the latex file again, does it give a stack trace?  This would tell you the function from which it is attempting to open the file. You can view the source code at that location. It may be that this needs to be made tramp aware. The package authors could be notified via a bug report or pull request of the enhancement.

Comment: I can compile the latex from the shell on the remote host no problem.  M-: (setq debug-on-error t)  give no stack trace. But I have the stack trace of latex, or auctex. It's just telling me that it cannot find the file I'm asking it to compile.

Comment: For me, it works. If I apply `C-c C-c`, I am asked for the command. `pdflatex` is the default, I hit `RET` in order to confirm. According to the traces, it is called then remotely lke this: `pdflatex \\nonstopmode\\input test.tex`. Please try to perform this starting with `emacs -Q`, maybe you have some settings in your `.emacs` which confuse Tramp.

Comment: Indeed you are right. I'll keep emacs -Q in mind. I'll try to find the culprit and will update soon. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus were you able to achieve the same results with your default emacs (without emacs -Q)?

Comment: Yes, just starting *emacs* gives the same result. Note, that I don't configure tex/latex/auctex in my .emacs.

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with auctex but I could not sort it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: and I learned this patch from this mailing list:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2008-05/msg00007.html

The fix requires changing one line in the file `tex-buf.el` which I was able to find in `.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-12.2.0/tex-buf.el`, although the location of the file may depend on your particular set-up.

as you can see, the one function changed was: `start-process` to `start-file-process`

```
*** 577,584 ****
          (lambda (process name)
            (message (concat name ": done."))))
      (if TeX-process-asynchronous
!       (let ((process (start-process name buffer TeX-shell
!                                     TeX-shell-command-option command)))
          (if TeX-after-start-process-function
              (funcall TeX-after-start-process-function process))
          (TeX-command-mode-line process)
--- 577,584 ----
          (lambda (process name)
            (message (concat name ": done."))))
      (if TeX-process-asynchronous
!       (let ((process (start-file-process name buffer TeX-shell
!                                          TeX-shell-command-option command)))
          (if TeX-after-start-process-function
              (funcall TeX-after-start-process-function process))
          (TeX-command-mode-line process)
```